# Java - No se referencia una variable de matriz a otro método de la misma clase

Tags: java, matrices, paso-por-referencia

Estoy haciendo un cartón de bingo que debe cumplir con ciertas condiciones, como el rango de números que puede haber en cada fila, y por supuesto, que no se repitan los números. Por lo tanto, hice un ciclo `do while` para que se genere un número random hasta que éste cumpla las condiciones.

La comprobación de que el número no se repita la hice en un método aparte, pero éste no toma el valor previamente asignado al espacio de la matriz. Éste es mi código:

```
public class Interfaz {

JFrame juego;
JPanel bingo, buttons, cajas[][];
JLabel x;
int valores[][], n;
double m;

public static void main(String[] a) {
    Interfaz vo = new Interfaz();
    vo.Crear();
}

public void Crear(){
    juego = new JFrame();
    juego.setSize(330, 606);

    bingo = new JPanel();
    bingo.setSize(326, 392);
    bingo.setBackground(java.awt.Color.red);

    bingo.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,5));
    cajas = new JPanel[6][5];
    valores = new int[5][5];
    BINGO(bingo);
    for(int i = 0; i < cajas.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cajas[0].length; j++){

            cajas[i][j] = new JPanel();
            cajas[i][j].setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            switch(j){
                case 0:
            do{
                m = Math.random() * 16;
                n = (int) m;
                valores[i][j] = n;
            }
            while(n <= 0 || !unique(j, valores));
            x = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n));
            break;

                case 1:
            do{
                m = Math.random() * 31;
                n = (int) m;
                valores[i][j] = n;
            }
            while(n <= 15 || !unique(j, valores));                
            x = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n));
            break;

                case 2:
            do{
                m = Math.random() * 46;
                n = (int) m;
                valores[i][j] = n;
            }
            while(n <= 30 || !unique(j, valores));                
            x = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n));
            break;

                case 3:
            do{
                m = Math.random() * 61;
                n = (int) m;
                valores[i][j] = n;
            }
            while(n <= 45 || !unique(j, valores));                
            x = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n));
            break;

                case 4:
            do{
                m = Math.random() * 76;
                n = (int) m;
                valores[i][j] = n;
            }
            while(n <= 60 || !unique(j, valores));                
            x = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n));
            break;
            }
            if (i == 2 && j == 2){
                valores[i][j] = 0;
                x = new JLabel("✶");
                Font symbol = new Font("Segoe UI Symbol", Font.PLAIN, 36);
                x.setFont(symbol);
            }
            cajas[i][j].add(x);
            cajas[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(java.awt.Color.BLACK, 1));
            cajas[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            bingo.add(cajas[i][j]);
        }
    }

    buttons = new JPanel();

    juego.add(bingo);
    juego.add(buttons);

    juego.setVisible(true);
}

//Esto es código que añade la palabra, no es importante
public void BINGO(JPanel bingo){...}

//Método donde valores[][] llega vacío
public boolean unique(int j, int valores[][]){
    boolean is = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < cajas.length ; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < cajas.length - 1; k++) {
            if (valores[i][j] == valores[k][j]){
                is = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return is;
}
}
```

He buscado bastante y he probado los siguientes métodos:

- El que está en el código, referenciarla directamente por los argumentos
- Usar la variable `private` y luego referenciarla como `this.valores[i][j]`
- Utilizar un método `getter`

Sin embargo, he puesto líneas de código para ver por consola el valor que toman las variables, y a la hora de dirigirse al otro método este se vuelve `0`.

Probablemente todo mi código no sea necesario, pero quizá en alguna parte se encuentra lo que impide referenciar la variable correctamente.
Si alguien pudiera decirme qué estoy haciendo mal o hablarme de otra forma diferente para lograrlo, lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Antes de `unique() ` el arreglo si tiene valores?

Comment: Sí, se le agrega un valor en cada caso del `switch` antes de llamar al método `unique()`

Comment: Cuando lo sacas del while, si pasa valores?

Comment: Estoy tratando de replicar tu código, me ha costado un poco y no encuentro razón evidente de que te devuelva 0. En que parte de `unique()` compruebas `valores[][]` ?

Comment: En el `if`, lo que utilizo es un ciclo anidado para comprobar si un valor de la matriz es igual a otro. Y sí, según la salida por consola, en el `do` se le asigna un valor que pierde en el siguiente método.

Comment: Creo que te sale 0 por que `valores[i][j] == valores[k][j]` en algún momento es 0. (Estas comprobando todo el arreglo de `valores[i][j]` )Y solo aparece ese valor por que es difícil que ramdom te de dos valores iguales en 5 oportunidades. Comprueba tus valores fuera del `if ` y veras que si pasan valores diferentes de 0.

Comment: Antes de utilizar la condición del `while` se le asigna un número a `variables[i][j]`, por lo que al entrar al ciclo, cualquiera que sea el valor será diferente de 0 (o podría coincidir, pero dudo que más de una vez). Además, como dije, puse salidas por consola para verificar el valor, y el problema está en que no se referencia en el siguiente método.

Comment: Por eso. No compruebes dentro del . Comprueba directamente dentro del `for`. Veras que todos los valores están ahí. Dentro del `if`solo se ven los que sean iguales. Recuerda que inicializaste el arreglo y los `int` siempre se inicializan en `0`. El if te esta mostrando todos los valores del arreglo que no estan inicializado.

Comment: Bien, un paso más cerca. Muchas gracias, ¿pero cómo hago la comparación, entonces?

Comment: Solo ocupas omitir el cero. Agrega un valor más al if donde omita el cero. De todos modos ya lo estas haciendo en el while ó la otra opción es que inicies el arreglo con valores en -1

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en el ciclo del método:

```
public boolean unique(int j, int valores[][]){
boolean is = true;

for (int i = 0; i < cajas.length ; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < cajas.length - 1; k++) {
        if (valores[i][j] == valores[k][j]){
            is = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return is;
```

Ya que cuando se comparan las demás líneas que no han sido asignadas y que comparten el valor de 0, es imposible salir del ciclo. En su lugar, referencio también el valor de la fila, y me aseguro de que no coincida con el del ciclo de comprobación.

```
public boolean unique(int i, int j){
    boolean is = true;

    for (int k = 0; k < cajas.length - 1; k++) {
        if (i != k){
            if (valores[i][j] == valores[k][j]){                    
                is = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```